# Manually Deleting Windows 7/Vista Backup files

Tags: windows-7, windows-vista, backup

If I manually delete many gigs of older files from my users Windows 7 and Vista backups, how will it impact the backup and restore catalogs. I fear that the catalogs may become corrupted or otherwise unusable if the expected files and folders listed in the catalog(s) are missing should I attempt a restore.

Thanks.

Comment: More info here on how the backups folders and files are structured http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/628-backup-user-system-files-delete-backups.html

Answer (score 6):

From [SevenForuns](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/628-backup-user-system-files-delete-backups.html):

Right click on the computer name of the backup that you want to delete, and click on Open.

[image]

If prompted, click on Continue and Yes (UAC).

[image]

Right click on the Backup Set `YYYY-MM-DD HHMMSS folder` of the backup period that you want to delete, and click on Delete.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I have for the longest time disliked windows 7's inability to prune older backups. So, I eventually made my own script that does it for me. I also created a simple installer for a scheduled task.

Here it is if anyone is interested:
https://github.com/BigRedBrent/WindowsBackupPruning

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question that was asked.

Answer (score 0):

I know that this also doesn't answer the question as asked, but...

Based on Brent's idea (credit where it is due) I have just written a windows batch script (which doesn't need AutoIt) which will prune your windows backup directory to delete older Backup Sets. You need to add a registry entry to get Windows Backup to create backup sets more frequently than once per year.

The script, registry entry and an example Task Scheduler xml file are available on [GitHub](https://github.com/Sophist-UK/WindowsScripts/tree/master/PruneBackups).